# Gulp Autoprefixer Not Working

Tags: css, sass, gulp, autoprefixer

I'm unable to get Autoprefixer to work with Gulp. I'm using opacity in my CSS, gradients, and transforms and there aren't any vendor prefixes showing up. Otherwise, everything else is working.

Here's my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var lr = require('tiny-lr');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var server = lr();
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

var onError = function (err) {  
  gutil.beep();
  console.log(err);
};

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/all.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions', 'safari 5', 'ie6', 'ie7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
        .pipe(livereload(server));
});


gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['js/fittext.js', 'js/fitvids.js', 'js/snap-scroll.js', 'js/cycle-min.js', 'js/all.js', 'js/respond.js'])
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/min'))
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/min'))
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
        .pipe(livereload(server));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('**/*.php').on('change', livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);  
});

gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

- I've searched and tried various solutions to this problem without avail. I've also tried changing `.pipe(gulp.dest(''))` to a specific directory (like [this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506171/gulp-autoprefixer-not-compiling-css3#answer-22592576)), without any luck.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

*** UPDATE ***

*I'd like to note my naivety on Autoprefixer adding a prefix for opacity, which it obviously does not.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

function onError(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
});
```

With this scss:

```
body {
    opacity: .5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: scale(.5);
    display: flex;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
body{opacity:.5;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-transform:scale(.5);-ms-transform:scale(.5);transform:scale(.5);display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}
```

So, I'm not sure what I'm doing different exactly except that I list my browsers differently. But I assume you've tried removing those etc.

Comment: Probably the best way to go about it. Reduce. Thanks for that.

I basically started from scratch like you did and now it's working.

I appreciate it man.

Comment: For me unfortunately it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710072/gulp-autoprefixer-giving-me-a-promise-error.

Comment: I'm not getting the prefixes with gulp-ruby-sass.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, putting the browsers in an array, instead of as arguments:

```
.pipe(autoprefixer({
    overrideBrowserlist: ['last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie6', 'ie7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4']
})
```

and you can add cascade by setting it true or false
 `cascade: false`

Comment: Thanks a ton for taking the time to help me out. I'm going to use an array going forward.

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm. You should however replace `ie6` and `ie7` for `ie 6` and `ie 7` otherwise you'll get the following error: `BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query`

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a while back but I have stumbled upon a similar problem.

Here is how I resolved it:

1. Add `browserlist` entry to `package.json`:

```
{
"browserslist": [
    'last 2 versions', 
    'safari 5', 
    'ie6', 
    'ie7', 
    'ie 8',
    'ie 9', 
    'opera 12.1', 
    'ios 6', 
    'android 4'
  ]
}
```

2. Install `autoprefixer`

`npm i --save-dev autoprefixer`

3. Install `postcss`

`npm i --save-dev postcss`

4. Modify the pipe in `gulpfile.js` to be:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
        .pipe(livereload(server));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a bit more up to date and inline with these instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer#gulp

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return gulp.src('css/styles.css')
   .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest ('build'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('css/styles.css', gulp.series(['styles']));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing that I see is:

```
.pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
```

A small change in syntax there:

```
.pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
```

Beyond that, I have had success by piping the compiled sass to the destination and then running autoprefixer.

```
.pipe(sass())
.pipe(gulp.dest(''))
.pipe(autoprefixer())
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I started from scratch like @donnywals suggested and it's now working.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer it's correct to use "last 2 versions" in gulp-autoprefixer

Comment: To add to @bogatyrjov comment. The order of pipes in your example is not correct. Firstly the code should be autoprefixed and then put into a new destination which resolves to `.pipe(sass()).pipe(autoprefixer()).pipe(gulp.dest(''))`.