# gulp sass sourcemaps and autoprefixer not working

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, autoprefixer, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-autoprefixer

I am unable to get the autoprefixer working with gulp sass. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions' ]}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

I followed the solution in related question but couldn't get it done. Here is the link : [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074093/gulp-autoprefixer-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the sourcemaps and autoprefix functionality so thought of sharing. Here is my gulpfile.js :

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vishal's answer is correct. I found that having `autoprefixer` and `sourcemaps` together was not working, *ONLY* when specifying a folder for the sourcemap's file.

`.pipe(sourcemaps.write('/assets/blahblah/blah')`

However, I was able to pass params to `autoprefixer` while leaving the destination folder for `sourcemaps` empty. It's also important to call the `write` function *BEFORE* calling `autoprefixer`

```
    return gulp.src('assets/FOLDER/public/scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(plumber(function (error) {
            gutil.log(error.message);
            this.emit('end');
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'compressed',
            sourceComments: 'normal',
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie 9', 'ios 6', 'android 4'], remove: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/FOLDER/dist/css'))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/FOLDER/dist/css'))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

```
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try to delete autoprefixer package!!**

My sourcemaps were crazy references code classes.

This is because autoprefixer is corrupted in gulp. Try uninstall that package and write prefixes in your code by yourself.

Hope this helps!

Worked for me.